# Capistrano deploy and assets:precompile too slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, deployment, capistrano, chaplinjs

"rake assets:precompile" and "cap deploy" consume extremely high amount of time whenever I call it (usually more then an hour). Sometimes deploy hang at all.
I use Rails 3.2.13, Ruby 1.9.3, OSX and Backbone's Chaplin Framework for frontend.
How can I speed up assets precompile and deploy task and what can cause such freezing?

My deploy.rb config:

```
# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-
require 'bundler/capistrano'
load 'deploy/assets'

set :application, "eyelashes"
set :rails_env, "production"

set :repository,  "git@github.com:eyelasher/repo.git"
set :scm, :git
set :deploy_via, :checkout
set :ssh_options, { :forward_agent => true }
default_run_options[:pty] = true


server "75.223.145.3", :app, :web, :db, :primary => true

set :bundle_without,  [:test]

set :user, 'deployer'
set :deploy_to, "/home/deployer/eyelasher"
set :branch, "master" unless exists?(:branch)
set :use_sudo, false

set :rvm_type, :user
set :rvm_ruby_string, :local
set :deploy_via, :checkout
before 'deploy:setup', 'rvm:create_gemset'

set :unicorn_conf, "#{deploy_to}/current/config/unicorn.rb"
set :unicorn_pid, "#{deploy_to}/shared/pids/unicorn.pid"

after "deploy", "deploy:migrate"
after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup"

require 'rvm/capistrano'
require 'thinking_sphinx/deploy/capistrano'

#after 'deploy:update_code', :roles => :app do
  #run "rm -f #{current_release}/config/database.yml"
  #run "ln -s #{deploy_to}/shared/config/database.yml #{current_release}/config/database.yml"
#end

namespace :deploy do
  task :restart do
    run "if [ -f #{unicorn_pid} ]; then kill -USR2 `cat #{unicorn_pid}`; else cd #{deploy_to}/current && bundle exec unicorn -c #{unicorn_conf} -E #{rails_env} -D; fi"
  end
  task :start do
    run "cd #{deploy_to}/current && bundle exec unicorn -c #{unicorn_conf} -E #{rails_env} -D;"
  end
  task :stop do
    run "if [ -f #{unicorn_pid} ] && [ -e /proc/$(cat #{unicorn_pid}) ]; then kill -QUIT `cat #{unicorn_pid}`; fi"
  end

end


# Thinking Sphinx typing shortcuts
namespace :ts do
  task :conf do
    thinking_sphinx.configure
  end
  task :in do
    thinking_sphinx.index
  end
  task :start do
    thinking_sphinx.start
  end
  task :stop do
    thinking_sphinx.stop
  end
  task :restart do
    thinking_sphinx.restart
  end
  task :rebuild do
    thinking_sphinx.rebuild
  end
end

# http://github.com/jamis/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb
# :default -> update, restart
# :update  -> update_code, symlink
namespace :deploy do
  desc "Link up Sphinx's indexes."
  task :symlink_sphinx_indexes, :roles => [:app] do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/db/sphinx #{release_path}/db/sphinx"
  end

  task :activate_sphinx, :roles => [:app] do
    symlink_sphinx_indexes
    thinking_sphinx.configure
    #thinking_sphinx.stop
    #thinking_sphinx.start
  end

  task :copy_images do
    run "cp -R #{shared_path}/public/images #{release_path}/public/images"
  end

  before 'deploy:update_code', 'thinking_sphinx:stop'
  after 'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:activate_sphinx'
  after 'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:copy_images'

end
```

Maybe I can speedup somehow by making changes in deploy configuration?

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying to a memory constrained VPS that sounds plausible. I'd recommend precompiling the assets on a a faster machine and checking them in to your repository.

There are various Gems and packages for speeding up asset precompilation by parallesing them, however in your situation that will likely make things MUCH worse!

Comment: Thanks for reply. However, I have really fast Leaseweb VDS.

Comment: *speed* doesn't make much difference! it's ram constraints mostly. You might try to remove the "initialize on precompile". Option which causes rails to boot the whole framework for every file that is to be recompiled.

Comment: I've set initialize_on_precompile = false in production config, however still to slow.

Comment: Then you'll need to upgrade your production hardware. Sorry the asset pipeline takes 5-7 minutes for me with just a handful (< 10) javascript files. It's just not built to perform when handling numerous files in front-end heavy applications like yours sounds like.